# Autodesk Vault 2015 API C# WPf Window not showing

Tags: c#, wpf, autodesk, autodesk-vault

This could be a Windows issue,

I created a Vault app which shows a WPF window when a button is clicked.
WPF window works fine one some machines and some machine when the button is clicked nothing happens.
Event if I try to show MessageBox.Show("test"); its not showing up.

Could someone explain what the issue might be with, why the window is not opening and how we debug in such scenarios.

Comment: Have you verified the plugin is actually loaded in the config file?  To be sure, you can make simple extension which adds a menu item. If the menu item shows then the config file is being read properly.

Comment: It was an issue with the built solution i created a new project and. Oved all the code it works.